# Can't clone any repos due to error died of signal 7

Tags: linux, git

So I just installed parrot os two days ago and it was working fine until it suddenly stopped cloning repos returning this output

```
git clone https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework
Cloning into 'metasploit-framework'...
error: git-remote-https died of signal 7
```

Tried multiple other repos too still the same except when I try to get a repo using ssh link (it's a private repo) it works just fine if I try any other repo that I don't own using ssh it doesn't work.

Message in `/var/log/messages`

```
May  4 18:51:33 chosey-parrot kernel: [ 4595.031755] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
May  4 18:51:34 chosey-parrot kernel: [ 4595.332929] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
May  4 18:51:58 chosey-parrot kernel: [ 4619.543781] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=3s
May  4 18:51:58 chosey-parrot kernel: [ 4619.543794] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
May  4 18:51:58 chosey-parrot kernel: [ 4619.543800] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
May  4 18:51:58 chosey-parrot kernel: [ 4619.543807] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 04 fe f3 a0 00 00 08 00
May  4 18:52:01 chosey-parrot kernel: [ 4622.691668] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=3s
May  4 18:52:01 chosey-parrot kernel: [ 4622.691680] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
May  4 18:52:01 chosey-parrot kernel: [ 4622.691686] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
May  4 18:52:01 chosey-parrot kernel: [ 4622.691693] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 04 fe f3 a0 00 00 08 00
```

Comment: Signal 7 is SIGBUS on x86 / ARM platforms - sounds like you have faulty hardware.

Comment: It was working fine though any idea how I can know what the problem is? @iBug

Comment: @iBug I ran a bad sectors check as I have read that it might be the cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages:

```
Sense Key : Medium Error
Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
```

indicates that there is a bad sector (or sector with bad checksum) on the given disk drive.  The auto-reallocate failed, but we can't tell if that's simply because the original data was unrecoverable, or the bad block table on the drive is full.  It's definitely a bad sign.

Git cannot fix your hardware.  On the positive side, though, you very likely have multiple copies of the various Git repositories (e.g., on GitHub or on multiple laptops or whatever).  Probably one of them is still good.  Fix (replace) the hardware and use the copies to reinstall the software.

See also [What do these disk errors in syslog mean?](https://serverfault.com/q/407007/549786)

Comment: Your hardware is (metaphorically, not quite literally) on fire. The fix is a fire extinguisher, not a software update.

Comment: Why is it working on windows though and not linux XD @torek

Comment: If you're getting disk errors, but only on one of two installed OSes, the reason is usually "luck": the bad spot on the drive is in use by one of the two OSes but not by the other. Or, sometimes it's a heat issue: one OS works the system harder than the other, causing it to heat up more. There are a lot of ways things can go wrong (and only a few ways things can go right) so "working well" has just a few causes while "failing" has many.